# XSL doesn't display value using Wicket XsltTransformerBehavior

Tags: java, xml, xslt, wicket

I write an Wicket application which should view a basic XML using XSL. When I let the code parse in w3schools tutorial, everything works. When I use Wickets XsltTransformerBehavior, I only see the basic table-structure, but no values.

XML:

```
<ecgreport timestamp="2000-01-01 00:00:00">
<patient>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>xyz</name>
    <sex>male</sex>
    <birthdate>1900-01-01 12:00:00</birthdate>
</patient>
</ecgreport>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h3>CDA Report <xsl:value-of select="ecgreport/@timestamp"/></h3>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acdff">
        <th>title</th>
        <th><xsl:text>value</xsl:text></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ecgreport/patient/name"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>sex</td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ecgreport/patient/id"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>birthdate</td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ecgreport/patient/birthdate"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

W3School reports the following (which is what I want):
[image: w3school result]

Wicket leaves me with that:
[image: wicket result]

Wicket code-snippet. The "data" is coming from an ResultSet, System.out shows the xml posted above:

```
XsltTransformerBehavior xslb = new XsltTransformerBehavior("ecg1.xsl");
xsl = new Label("last_cda",rs.getString("data"));
xsl.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
xsl.add(xslb);
add(xsl);
```

I tried it with Chrome, Firefox, IE10 - I guess they all support XSL by now. I guess I am losing the data within the transforming step. Do I need a DOM-Object for Input? Or have I made another noob-mistake?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your XSL. Have a look at the help page for Class XsltTransformerBehavior:

http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/transformer/XsltTransformerBehavior.html

It says:

> The containers tag will be the root element of the xml data applied for transformation to ensure the xml data are well formed (single root element). In addition the attribute xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.3-strict.dtd is added to the root element to allow the XSL processor to handle the wicket namespace.

In your case, I don't know what is your container's tag for ID last_cda (you need to check your markup HTML file). Let's suppose it's a div. So you need to specify that in your XSL's XPaths, which should then look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h3>CDA Report <xsl:value-of select="div/ecgreport/@timestamp"/></h3>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acdff">
        <th>title</th>
        <th><xsl:text>value</xsl:text></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="div/ecgreport/patient/name"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>sex</td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="div/ecgreport/patient/id"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>birthdate</td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="div/ecgreport/patient/birthdate"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```